# How to pass variable to react-router component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In component *TabContent* I need to render components depending on their order number. In functions **getFirstTabContent(), getSecondTabContent(), getThirdTabContent()** I determine what component (DummyTable, DummyChart or DummyList) will be the first, the second and the third by assigning it to variables. According to that I need to render it in *TabContent* component. But I have an error when write **component={firstTabContent}**. Error: *Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.*

```
var firstTabPath, secondTabPath, thirdTabPath,
        firstTabTitle, secondTabTitle, thirdTabTitle,
        firstTabContent, secondTabContent, thirdTabContent;

const getTabsTitlesInOrder = () => {
    for(var i = 0; i <tabsJson.tabs.length; i ++){
        switch(tabsJson.tabs[i].order){
            case 0:
                firstTabTitle = tabsJson.tabs[i].title;
                getFirstTabContent(firstTabTitle);
                break;
            case 1:
                secondTabTitle = tabsJson.tabs[i].title;
                getSecondTabContent(secondTabTitle);
                break;
            case 2:
                thirdTabTitle = tabsJson.tabs[i].title;
                getThirdTabContent(thirdTabTitle);
                break;
        }
    }
};

const getFirstTabContent = (firstTabTitle) => {
    switch (firstTabTitle) {
        case "Dummy Table":
            firstTabContent = <DummyTable/>;
            firstTabPath = "/dummyTable";
            break;
        case "Dummy Chart":
            firstTabContent = <DummyChart/>;
            firstTabPath = "/dummyChart";
            break;
        case "Dummy List":
            firstTabContent = <DummyList/>;
            firstTabPath = "/dummyList";
            break;
    }
};

const getSecondTabContent = (secondTabTitle) => {
    switch (secondTabTitle) {
        case "Dummy Table":
            secondTabContent = <DummyTable/>;
            secondTabPath = "/dummyTable";
            break;
        case "Dummy Chart":
            secondTabContent = <DummyChart/>;
            secondTabPath = "/dummyChart";
            break;
        case "Dummy List":
            secondTabContent = <DummyList/>;
            secondTabPath = "/dummyList";
            break;
    }
};

const getThirdTabContent = (thirdTabTitle) => {
    switch (thirdTabTitle) {
        case "Dummy Table":
            thirdTabContent = <DummyTable/>;
            thirdTabPath = "/dummyTable";
            break;
        case "Dummy Chart":
            thirdTabContent = <DummyChart/>;
            thirdTabPath = "/dummyChart";
            break;
        case "Dummy List":
            thirdTabContent = <DummyList/>;
            thirdTabPath = "/dummyList";
            break;
    }
};

class TabContent extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={firstTabPath} component={firstTabContent}/>
                <Route path={secondTabPath} component={secondTabContent}/>
                <Route path={thirdTabPath} component={thirdTabContent}/>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
};

class TabButtons extends React.Component{
    render() { 
        getTabsTitlesInOrder();
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="tabTitleWrapper">
                    <Link className="tabLink" to={firstTabPath}>
                        {firstTabTitle}
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="tabTitleWrapper">
                    <Link className="tabLink" to={secondTabPath}>
                        {secondTabTitle}
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="tabTitleWrapper">
                    <Link className="tabLink" to={thirdTabPath}>
                        {thirdTabTitle}
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class App extends React.Component{
    render() { 
        return(
            <div>
                <TabButtons />
                <TabContent />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>),
    document.getElementById('tab')
);
```

Comment: Try this `thirdTabContent = DummyTable` and so on for the others

Comment: Thanks you a lot!!! It works right